# Loop com colunas e rows

Tags: php, loop, bootstrap-4

Tenho tentando fazer assim:

```
<?php foreach ($unfollow as $row): ?>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <?php var_dump($row)?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Só que isso me tráz 1 `row` e uma coluna de 4.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O correto seria 1 row 3 colunas de `col-md-4`.

Como corrigir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode mudar o loop para as colunas:

```php
<div class="row">
  <?php foreach ($unfollow as $row): ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <?php var_dump($row)?>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Desta forma irá produzir:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Como o Bootstrap é responsivo, irá alinhas as colunas "col-md-4" com este espaçamento e automaticamente irá arranjar as colunas excedentes em nova linha.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Opa vlw amigo, deu certo

Answer (score 2):

Pode tentar desta forma, criando uma nova `.row` cada vez que um contador alcançar um múltiplo de `3` (veja comentários explicativos no código):

```
<?php
$col = 1; // contador do laço
$divrow = "<div class='row'>"; // HTML da .row
$ufsize = sizeof($unfollow); // tamanho da array
echo $divrow; // imprime a abertura da .row
foreach ($unfollow as $row):
?>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <?php var_dump($row)?>
   </div>
<?php
   // se chegar na coluna 3, ou o valor do contador for igual ao tamanho da array,
   // fecha a div
   if($col%3 == 0 || $col == $ufsize){
      echo "</div>"; // imprime o fechamento da div da .row
      // se o valor do contador for menor que o tamanho da array,
      // imprime a abertura do .row
      if($col < $ufsize) echo $divrow;
   }
   $col++; // incrementa o contador
?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Resolvi com o comentário do amigo à cima